# Angular Material Multiple Paginator in same Component and View

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, frontend

Have 2 tables in view and displaying some graphs along with the tables, everything works except  the paginator on 2 tables. , which takes data from 2 sources.   When the Paginator of upper table clicked  the lower table changes the data,

component have initialized the paginator and tables with data sources,

> My Component.ts

```
  export class FinancialMetricsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  pageSize = 20;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<SnowTicket> | null;
  utilizationDataSource: MatTableDataSource<Utilization> | null;

  @ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();
  @ViewChildren(MatSort) sort = new QueryList<MatSort>();




ngOnInit() {

    this.changeDataAccordingToDate();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.data$.pipe(
      filter(Boolean)
    ).subscribe((tickets) => {
      this.accountsData = tickets;
      this.dataSource.data = tickets;
    });

    this.pcsService.getUtilizationData('120').subscribe(resources => {
      this.utilizationSubject$.next(resources);
    });
    this.utilizationDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.utilizationData$.pipe(
      filter(Boolean)
    ).subscribe((tickets) => {
      this.utilizationData = tickets;
      this.utilizationDataSource.data = tickets;
    });
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator.toArray()[0];
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[0];

    this.utilizationDataSource.paginator = this.paginator.toArray()[1];
    this.utilizationDataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[1];

    }
}
```

In view here only added the tables, that have the paginators.   When the paginator in upper has table removed the lower table paginator works. else only the upper paginator works, when it clicked the lower table changes data,

> View.html

```
<fury-list name="AWS Resources Expenditure" [columns]="columns" (filterChange)="onFilterChange($event)">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
      <ng-container *ngIf="column.notCurrency" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.name }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span class="fury-mobile-label">{{ column.name }}</span> {{ row[column.property] }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!column.notCurrency" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.name }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span class="fury-mobile-label">{{ column.name }}</span> {{ row[column.property] | currency }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="visibleColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: visibleColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginator class="paginator" [pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>
</fury-list>



<fury-list name="AWS EC2 Utilization (Past 120 days)" [columns]="utilizationColumns" (filterChange)="onFilterChangeU($event)">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="utilizationDataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of utilizationColumns">
      <ng-container *ngIf="!column.isAvg" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.name }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span class="fury-mobile-label">{ { column.name }}</span> {{ row[column.property] }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="column.isAvg" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.name }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span class="fury-mobile-label">{{ column.name }}</span> {{ row[column.property]}}
          <mat-icon *ngIf="row[column.property] < 10"> trending_down</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="row[column.property] > 70"> trending_up</mat-icon>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="visibleColumnsU"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: visibleColumnsU;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginatorU class="paginator" [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>
</fury-list>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would bind the paginators based on their template variable and not rely on the `QueryList` to contain them in the proper order.

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('paginatorU') paginatorU: MatPaginator;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[0];
  this.utilizationDataSource.paginator = this.paginatorU;
  this.utilizationDataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[1];
}
```

Comment: is there a way to add id #sortU in html and refer using ViewChild in typescript?

Comment: This will not work with a back button you will get the dreaded "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'"

Comment: @thxmike, what's the solution to that problem?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the previous answers, the component should have as many paginators as needed and they should be named:

```
@ViewChild('firstPaginator', {static: true}) firstPaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('secondPaginator', {static: true}) secondPaginator: MatPaginator;
```

And the view should call these paginators:

```
    <mat-paginator #firstPaginator [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>

    <mat-paginator #secondPaginator [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to define two distinct paginators if you want them to work independently.

Comment: added 2 paginators., but the issue still exists

Answer (score 1):

on your FinancialMetricsComponent add:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

and add public function

```
public handlePageBottom(event: PageEvent) {
    this.paginator.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.paginator.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    this.paginator.page.emit(event);
}
```

in HTML file put two paginators:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="countItems" #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50]"></mat-paginator>

<mat-table></mat-table>

<mat-paginator (page)="handlePageBottom($event)" [pageSize]="paginator.pageSize"
                   [pageIndex]="paginator.pageIndex" [length]="paginator.length"
                   [pageSizeOptions]="paginator.pageSizeOptions"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: By far the best answer, IMO